# Embedding YT videos is changing my website colors. Very weird problem

Tags: html, css, web, youtube

This is very weird problem. I can't solve it.
I am embedding YT video using the code provided by YT, using:

```
<iframe width="584" height="330" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/N739-Wzmf18" style="border:none;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Next to it I am adding some text with title that has some color.

The problem is the color text is getting dark. When the website is loading or refreshed it has a good color for a second and then it turn to much darker.

The rest of the text that is white is not affected that way.

Also the "footer" that is a "separate-being" and also has some text in color that color is turned to dark. In this case I just use simple  to color that text.

When I getting rid of yt code (or even just src="") the colors are ok again.

In one case when I got only YT videos without text I used  insted of  and it solved the problem for this case for the "footer". But it not working when there is some text added next to YT video.

I tested on Chrome, Edge and Brave (maybe they use the same engine)
You can check it yourself:

1. Select SHORTS
2. Click Refresh couple of times - you shoud see that red color titles and red year on footer flickers from bright to dark.
3. Select another menu like INFO to compare good red color with the darken one (the footer example will be the best)

The link:
http://www.mateuszstaniszew.pl/index.php?m=1

Comment: ps. I also tried display: flex, but didn't helped...

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code with the problem is linked externally. Please [edit] this question to include the [minimal code that exhibits the issue](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. [Code linked externally may not be permanently available, and may not be licensed such that it can be used in answers](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a stab in the dark here and suggest that your problem is with `font-weight` rather than `color`. At least for me, bolding the text looks like the closest to page-load render.

Try adding `font-weight: bold;` to `.text-title` in your CSS.

My theory is that an asynchronous script is injecting some styles that overwrite wherever .text-title is inheriting the bold weight from. I can't find the proof in your styles, but I'm feeling optimistic :)